# Why are the terminal Hydrogen bonds in diborane lost during alkylation?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Considering the fact that the bridge h bonds in diborane are weaker according to the answer  to the following question..>>.[Why are bridge bonds in diborane longer than the terminal H bonds?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94067/why-are-bridge-bonds-in-diborane-longer-than-the-terminal-h-bonds)
Why is then the terminal H bonds instead of the bridge H bond
lost during alkylation of diborane?
Is it energetically more favourable? If yes,Is there any reason why it is so?